# how to impliment application multilanguage select in iphone?

Tags: iphone, programming-languages

Everyone

I need to implement application for multi-languages select for only this application not for whole device.

please,give me idea for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. every, but every visual component that contains text, should be given an outlet.
2. make 2 plist files that will contain the text in English and e.g. French. every text in your application will have it's key in the plis file. Here is an example of my plis files:

[image]

[image]

Now you must do an interface to let the user choose the language, and save in NSUserDefaults the selected option. And finally, in each viewDidLoad (or viewWillAppear), check that default object, and set the text to all your outlets depending on the selected language. You must know how to read from plists, this is another question. Cheers!

Here some code:

```
    //suppose you have only English and German:
    NSDictionary *selectedLangDick;
    if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"selected_lang"] isEqualToString:@"german"])
        selectedLangDick = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"lang_de.plist"];
       else
        selectedLangDick = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"lang_en.plist"];

//now you set the text to all your outlets within the currently loaded controller:
        [cancelButtonOutlet setTitle:[selectedLangDick objectForKey:@"cancel"]];
        [backButtonOutlet setTitle:[selectedLangDick objectForKey:@"back"]];
        [pleaseWaitLabelOutlet setText:[selectedLangDick objectForKey:@"progress_send_password"]];
blablabla
blablabla
```

Of course, you will have to set (at the very first application launch) the default language to English (or German, whatever, it's important to set it, not to leave it nil). And of course you will have to set `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"selected_lang"]` to the selected language when the user does it.

Comment: Thanks,can you give some sample code for this, explain in brief ?

Comment: you mean we set the language before the (UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions ,but how to set this ?

Comment: no, in didFinishLaunching check a default object for the key e.g. "this_is_the_first_launch", if it is nil, set it to any object like @"asta_la_vista_baby", so it will not be nil anymore. so every time when your didFinishLaunching is getting called, you will be checking that default object, and only at the first launch it will be nil. this way you will know if you are running the application for the first time, so at that time you should set your default language dictionary